# For which values of $a\in\mathbb{R} $ the equation $2 \log(x+3)=\log(ax)$ has exactly one root?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, logarithms

I have to investigate the possible roots of the equation according to $a$, i.e. i have to see whether there is only one root, two roots, or no roots and also what their sign is each time. This is from a book i'm reading and the answer it gives is $a<0$ or $a=12$.

Now first we have to to make the restriction that $x>-3$ due to logarithm. What is troubling me is the $a<0$ part.

In the solution it says that after getting rid of the logarithms we have $x^2-(a-6)x+9$. Now if $a<0 \land x>0$, then $\log(ax)$ is undefined so the equation has no solution. But we're asked about $a$, not $x$. So it proceeds to say that if $a<0 \land x<0$, i.e. $-3<x<0$ (due to our restriction) then:

> Let $f(x)=x^2-(a-6)x+9$, so $f(-3)=3a<0$. [The following is primarily what i don't understand.] This means that $-3$ will be between the two roots $x_1$ and $x_2$, so $x_1<-3<x_2<0$, but since we have the constriction $-3<x<0$ then $x_1$ is not possible so $x_2$ is one and only root of the original equation. Thus for $a<0$ there is exactly one root.

How could they even do that, plug $-3$ for $f(x)$ to test the roots of the equation, since for $x=-3$ the equation is not defined. Also what i'm not sure i understand is why it says that since $f(-3)<0$ then $x_1<-3<x_2$. I would like to understand that. Help please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of plugging $-3$, I think you should take a limit to $-3$.

Comment: Yes, whatever is the case, for $x=-3$ why does it say  that $x_1<-3<x_2$. Since $a<0$ then of course there are two negative roots due to the discriminant's sign, but why $x_1<-3<x_2$ i don't get.

Comment: Is $x \in \mathbb R$ ? Or can it be complex ?

Comment: No $x\in\mathbb{R}$ only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case we're considering here is the one where exactly one of the two roots *of the quadratic* $f$ is to the right of $-3$. That is the same as saying that $x=-3$ lies between the two roots of $f$. And from our general knowledge of how quadratics behaves, since the $x^2$ coefficient of $f$ is positive, the points between the two roots are exactly the ones where $f(x)<0$. Thus $-3$ is such a point (implying that the logarithmic equation will have exactly one solution) if and only if $f(-3)<0$.

Note that $f(x)$ is just a quadratic polynomial -- when we're investigating the shape and position of the parabola, it makes perfect sense to evaluate *it* at any $x$, even though the original logarithmic equation that led you to consider that polynomial is only defined for some values.

Comment: It was an intuitive approach after all. I should have been more concentrated. Your answer helped me grow in strength and in wisdom. :) Thank you all.

Comment: Definitely a +1 for understanding OPs exact issue and tackling that as succinctly as possible.

Answer (score 2):

For the functions to be defined we must have $x >-3$ and $ax>0$

Now take **Case 1: a>0**. Then $x>0$ and $x >-3$ So, in conclusion $x>0$.

So, $(x+3)^2 =ax$ should have exactly one positive root (since x>0)

But $x^2+x(6-a) +9=0$ has either two positive roots or two negative roots or non-real roots ( as product of roots is positive =9).

So, the only option is two equal positive roots which give $a=12$ (using discriminant.

**Case 2: a< 0**. Now we must have $x >-3$ and $x<0$.

So,  $f(x)=x^2+x(6-a) +9=0$ must have exactly one root between $(-3, 0)$.

So, $f(-3)f(0) <0$ which is equivalent to $a < 0$.

So, $a<0$ or $a=12$

Comment: There is a single small mistake here: $f$ having exactly one root between $-3$ and $0$ does not allow to immediately deduce that $f(-3) f(0) < 0$; further steps are needed to insure that the root is not a double root and an extremum in the same time. This is not difficult to add to the proof, and it should be done for the sake of its completeness.

Answer (score 1):

Reducing $2\log(x+3)=\log(ax)$ to
$$
(x+3)^2=ax
$$
should be done with some care. This equation should either have a single solution (zero discriminant), or just one solution satisfying $x+3>0$ and $ax>0$.

First we can dismiss the easy case: the discriminant of $x^2+(6-a)x+9=0$ is $(6-a)^2-36=a^2-12a$. This is zero for $a=12$ or $a=0$, but this last value is not acceptable. The double root when $a=12$ is $x=3$ that satisfies the conditions $x+3>0$ and $12x>0$.

For the harder case, we first have to ensure the discriminant is positive, so either $a<0$ or $a>12$.

For $a>12$ the roots are both positive, so they both satisfy $x+3>0$ and $ax>0$. Thus this is not part of our solution.

For $a<0$ we have $6-a>0$ so both roots are negative and we need to ensure just one of them is in the interval $(-3,0)$.

Let $f(x)=x^2+(6-a)x+9$; then $f(-3)=3a<0$ and $f(0)=9>0$; the graph of $f$ is a parabola which is decreasing in the interval $(-\infty,(6-a)/2)$ and increasing in the interval $((6-a)/2,\infty)$. Since $(6-a)/2>0$, we see that just one root is in the interval $(-3,0)$, as required.